# Imagem cujo texto não está traduzido na página de ajuda sobre sinalizar

Tags: bug, tradução

Nesta [página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) no item "Como faço para sinalizar?" tem uma imagem (não seria melhor texto?), e a mesma está em inglês. O print é somente da pergunta mas sinalização de resposta o caso é o mesmo.

Acho que seria bom colocar texto em português, até porque pelo que vi estas sinalizações estão todas traduzidas.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]